# Reading protobuf Message file in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a pb file abc.pb file.

I need to read the file by retaining its format i.e. dont want to convert pb file to string and then again reconverting it.

Currently I m trying options with

```
    with open(data, "rb") as file_handle:
        data = file_handle.read()
```

But this converts that into bytes. How to read them as Message. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you specify what you want to do with it? Is this a trained model in pb format or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protobuf is a binary encoding and -- generally -- you'll use a schema (types) to decode messages.

Protobuf types are described in `proto` files and compiled (using `protoc`) into langauge-specific stubs that can be used to encode|decode messages.

See [Protocol Buffer Basics: Python](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) which includes an example [reading a message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#reading-a-message).

There are ways to [decode](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode) binary files without a schema but it's more challenging.

So:

Either: See whether you can obtain the Python stubs for the pb file you're trying to decode

Or: If you have `proto` files, use `protoc` (see example above) to generate the Python stubs

Or: Use a tool like's Marc's (above) or some other library that will decode [encoded](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) arbitary messages for you.